# Access a Java Hashtable with int and byte key

Tags: java

I have a Hashtable to find objects by number. Let's assume I do

```
Hashtable<Integer, MyClass> table = ...
table.put(10, myObject);
```

and query this with a byte or Byte object that also has value 10, then I get no result.

```
Byte b = new Byte(10);
table.get(b); // -> null
table.get((int)b); // -> myObject
table.get(10); // -> myObject
table.get((byte)10); // -> null
```

Byte and Integer objects are different, I know. But it compiles and both have the same hashcode, namely the value 10. Shouldn't both find the object?
The byte value on one of my cases is unchangeable. I can cast it to int but I would like to understand what's going on here.

Edit: Let me make clearer what my problem was. I thought as this hashlist has an Integer as key type, either I should get an error if I use something different that an int (which is converted into integer) or another number type is automatically converted into int. This made me wonder.

Comment: @shmosel I don't see where my question is similar to the one you linked to. The linked question is why two objects can have the same hashcode. My question is why are objects with the same hashcode treated differently. This is another point of view on hashes.+

Comment: Do you mean the duplicate question? Because that one is pretty similar

Comment: Please read both questions again and you will see that the actual problem in my understanding is something very different.

Comment: It's the same question. Two objects can have the same hashcode because they're still treated differently, as explained in that answer.

Comment: The answer fits to both questions, but the background is different. Sorry for that, but it really is ;-) I have to admit if I had thought more about this fact then I should have found the answer on my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not enough they got same `hashCode`, when you call `get` method, the key should also **equals** the one you `put` before.

`Byte` and `Integer` are different classes, so they are not equal with each other, that's why you got null with `table.get(b)` or `table.get((byte)10)`.

Comment: Ok the equals was what I missed! Then it is clear to me why my keys are different.